# MVC Membership Database Context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

How do I connect to the membership database to retrieve a list of user accounts?  For example I have this to connect to my profiles:

```
    Private db As UserProfileDbContext = New UserProfileDbContext

    '
    ' GET: /UserProfile/

    Function Index() As ViewResult
        Return View(db.UserProfiles.ToList())
    End Function
```

There doesn't seem to be any user account database context specified in the account model.  Should I create one, or is there a better way to retrieve all user accounts into a list like above?

Edit:

I have this code in the controller:

```
'
' GET: /Account/ViewRegistries

Function ViewRegistries() As ViewResult
    Return View(Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast(Of MembershipUser).ToList)
End Function
```

My view:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of MyBlog.RegisterModel)

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            UserId
        </th>
        <th>
            CompanyId
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.UserName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.Company)
        </td>
    </tr>
Next

</table>
```

But it produces an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Security.MembershipUser]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyBlog.RegisterModel]'.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just Create one, or Go to login, Register and register there. Since there are no users present, you won't have anything at first. 

You will have to create it.

Comment: Also you can try using the aspnet configuration in visual studio to create it. 
Alternatively you can use aspnet_regsql.exe in Visual studio command prompt

Comment: @Rajesh:  When I publish to a server can I still use the aspnet configuration?  It doesn't look password protected.

Comment: Once published, you should not be using the aspnet configuration. Its useful in a development machine. You may then upload the web.config and the database to the published server.

Comment: That's what I thought.  So, I am trying to build an interface for an admin user to CRUD other users.

Comment: Yes, Its pretty easy. Use the Membership framework extensively. 
Membership.CreateUser, DeleteUser, AddUser, Get roles, delete role, adduserinrole . Alternatively you can also use linq2sql for other operations. But use Membership as much as possible to make your life easy.

Comment: welcome, upvote my comments whichever you liked :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the membership provider:

```
Membership.GetAllUsers()
```

Once you register users this will return the list of all users in the database.

Comment: Yes. Darin is right. But make sure your connectionstring is right.Then register some users in the database.

Comment: Will this go into my model and be used the same way as db.UserProfiles.ToList()?  Or will I have to do more work?

Comment: This will query the membership provider and return a list of `MembershipUser`. If you want to get the list of usernames simply use LINQ: `Dim usernames = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast(Of MembershipUser).Select(Function(u)u.UserName).ToList()`.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to get more than just the usernames.  I would like to create a datatable showing all the data of all the users.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov:  Any idea on my last question?

Comment: Sorry, I was asking you if you knew how to not just get a list of usernames, but instead get a list of all fields similar to the functionality of the db.UserProfiles.ToList() from above.

Comment: What fields are you interested in? Simply remove the `.Select` extension method that selects the username only and you will get a list of `MembershipUser` containing all properties.

Comment: I tried the code but it gives me an error.  I updated the question.  can you help with this?

Comment: Your view is strongly typed to some `MyBlog.RegisterModel` class but you are passing a `List(Of MembershipUser)`. This obviously cannot work. So you will have to update your view model type: `@ModelType IEnumerable(Of List(Of MembershipUser))`.

Comment: Thanks, that removes the error.  However, I then get a new compilation error.  I assume it is the way I am accessing the variables.  Can I no longer access them like @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.UserName)?  How can they be accessed?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I changed from your suggestion to @ModelType IEnumerable(Of MembershipUser) and it seems to be working.  Thanks :)